# Why document.body.style.backgroundColor doesn't work in -webkit-linear-gradient?

Tags: javascript, colors

I have a javascript function that changes the background color of the page. When the page changes color there is another function which takes the **document.body.style.backgroundColor** property and applies it to a **-webkit-linear-gradient**, like this:

```
function setGradientColor() {
            document.getElementById("gradient").style.background=
            "-webkit-linear-gradient(right," + document.body.style.backgroundColor + ", transparent)";
    }
```

My question is: why if I set a color string like "#fc4" instead of document.body.style.backgroundColor I see the color in the gradient, but when I set document.body.style.backgroundColor I don't see anything?

My backgroundColor is setted in my CSS code also...

Comment: What is `document.body.style.backgroundColor`?

Comment: `document.body.style.backgroundColor` returns a RGBA value, not a HEX value.

Comment: All right but -webkit-linear-gradient accepts both HEX and RGBA values, I can not figure where the error is.